# JS - определить фокус на элементе

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как определить фокус на элементе в моменте ?

Есть функция Document.hasFocus() - но, как я понял эта функция возвращает true/false - если фокус есть или нет на всем документе, а не на конкретном документе.

Можно повесить addEventListener на элемент с "focus", но этот случай покажет момент, когда фокус установится на указанный элемент.

А вот, как посмотреть в момент вызова функции - есть ли фокус на элементе или нет ? То есть аналог функции .hasFocus() - только для элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью **[activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)** попробовать.

```
// отслеживаемы элемент
let someEl = document.getElementById('myID');

// Проверка есть ли фокус
let isFocused = (document.activeElement === someEl );
```

---

На jquery будет так:

```
if ($("#myID").is(":focus")) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант:

```js
var checkFocus = (el) => el === document.querySelector(':focus');

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(checkFocus(input2));
});
```

```html
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<input id="input3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, сделать доп свойство для нужного элемента, а дальше навесить события onfocus и onblur на элемент, которые будут устанавливать статус фокуса на элемент

Пример:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('test');
var check = document.getElementById('check');


input.onfocus = function() {
  this.focused = true;
};
input.onblur = function() {
  this.focused = false;
};

setInterval(function() {
  check.innerHTML = input.focused;
});
```

```html
<input id='test'>
<div id='check'></div>
```